# Filtering based on Joining Multiple Tables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am using MySQL and I have three table:

```
Table: Salesperson
ID | Name | Age | Salary
1  | Abe  | 61  | 140000
2  | Bob  | 34  | 44000
5  | Chris| 34  | 40000
7  | Dan  | 41  | 52000
8  | Ken  | 57  | 115000
11 | Joe  | 38  | 38000

Table: Customer
ID | Name     | City     | Industry_Type
4  | Samsonic | pleasant | J
6  | Panasung | oaktown  | J
7  | Samony   | jackson  | B
9  | Orange   | jackson  | B

Table: Orders
Number | order_date | cust_id | salesperson_id | Amount
10     | 1996-08-02 | 4       | 2              |540 
20     | 1999-01-30 | 4       | 8              |1800
30     | 1995-07-14 | 9       | 1              |460
40     | 1998-01-29 | 7       | 2              |2400
50     | 1998-02-03 | 6       | 7              |600
60     | 1998-03-02 | 6       | 7              |720
70     | 1995-05-06 | 9       | 7              |150
```

I want to find the names of all salespeople that do not have any orders with Samsonic and who have made at least 1 order

My expected Result is:

```
Name
Abe
Dan
```

I tried:

```
SELECT Distinct(s.name)
FROM Orders o 
INNER JOIN Salesperson s
ON o.salesperson_id = s.ID
INNER JOIN Customer c
ON c.ID = o.cust_id
WHERE s.name NOT IN(
select s.name where c.name='Samsonic'
);
```

However the result I get is:

```
Name
Dan
Bob
Abe
```

I believe Bob shows up since he made another order that was not Samsonic. How can I get my intended result while still joining all three tables? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your subquery, you are referencing tables in the outer query.

The code below should fix your issue.

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.name
FROM salesperson s 
INNER JOIN orders o ON s.id = o.salesperson_id
INNER JOIN customer c ON o.cust_id = c.id
WHERE s.name NOT IN (
    SELECT s.name
    FROM  salesperson s 
    INNER JOIN orders o ON s.id = o.salesperson_id
    INNER JOIN customer c ON o.cust_id = c.id
    WHERE c.name = 'Samsonic'
);
```

Comment: This query does not work if multiple persons have the same name.  You need to compare IDs not name.

Comment: Yes of course, but it's not part of the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to write such a query, but the given specification:

> I want to find the names of all salespeople that do not have any orders with Samsonic and who have made at least 1 order

maps directly to:

```
SELECT s.name
FROM salesperson s 
WHERE s.id NOT IN (
        SELECT o.salesperson_id
        FROM  orders o INNER JOIN customer c ON o.cust_id = c.id
        WHERE c.name = 'Samsonic')
  AND s.id IN (SELECT salesperson_id FROM orders);
```

The main/outer query finds the names of sales people, the first subquery removes sales people which have orders with Samsonic, and the second subquery makes sure the sales person has made a least one order.